# Conditional Column Select based on column pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

I have input dataset of all elements

```
+-------------------------+----------------+------------------------+-----+----------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|ingestion_connection_name|ingestion_source|hostname                |port |database  |schema      |username |topicname                  |brokers                                                    |startingoffsets|
+-------------------------+----------------+------------------------+-----+----------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
|oradom_conn              |ORACLE          |wdummyRdbora01          |1521 |domabcr   |n4domop2    |n4domop2 |                           |                                                           |               |
|hdfs_connection          |HDFS            |                        |     |          |            |         |                           |                                                           |               |
|kafka_connection         |KAFKA           |                        |     |          |            |         |streaming.ELK.poc          |abcdedfdev001:9092,abcdedfdev002:9092,abcdedfdev003:9092|               |
+-------------------------+----------------+------------------------+-----+----------+------------+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Expected output

```
{
    "ingestion_connection_details" : [
    {
    "ingestion_connection_name": "oradom_conn",
    "ingestion_source" : "ORACLE",
    "hostname" : "wdummyRdbora01",
    "port" :"1521",
    "database" :"domabcr",
    "schema" :"domabcrsc",
    "username" :"n4domop2"
    },
    {
        "ingestion_connection_name": "kafka_connection",
        "ingestion_source" : "kafka",
        "topicname" : "streaming.ELK.poc",
        "brokers" : "abcdedfdev001:9092,abcdedfdev002:9092,abcdedfdev003:9092",
        "startingOffsets" :  ""
    },
    {
    "ingestion_connection_name": "hdfs_connection",
    "ingestion_source" : "hdfs"
    }
    ]
}
```

Code

```
results = df.toJSON().map(lambda j: json.loads(j)).collect()
with open('/hadoopData/bdipoc/poc/logs/data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(results, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```

This code produces only a array of records with all elements . But how ever I wanted input to be written into a flat file with ingestion_connection_details tag and have only concerned columns for each source type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of Spark's [sql functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/sql/index.html) to get the required result:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn("map", F.map_from_arrays(F.array([F.lit(c) for c in df.columns]),F.array(df.columns)))\
  .withColumn("filtered_map", F.expr("map_filter(map, (k,v) -> v is not null)")) \
  .withColumn("json", F.to_json("filtered_map"))
```

- column `map` contains a map that maps all column names to their respective values
- in column `filtered_map` only those keys are kept where the values are not empty
- column `json` contains the final json strings

Starting with test data

```
+----+----+----+---+
|  c1|  c2|  c3| c4|
+----+----+----+---+
|   A|   B|null|  D|
|  10|null|  20| 30|
|null|null|null| 30|
+----+----+----+---+
```

the final result is

```
+----+----+----+---+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|c1  |c2  |c3  |c4 |map                                           |filtered_map                  |json                           |
+----+----+----+---+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|A   |B   |null|D  |{c1 -> A, c2 -> B, c3 -> null, c4 -> D}       |{c1 -> A, c2 -> B, c4 -> D}   |{"c1":"A","c2":"B","c4":"D"}   |
|10  |null|20  |30 |{c1 -> 10, c2 -> null, c3 -> 20, c4 -> 30}    |{c1 -> 10, c3 -> 20, c4 -> 30}|{"c1":"10","c3":"20","c4":"30"}|
|null|null|null|30 |{c1 -> null, c2 -> null, c3 -> null, c4 -> 30}|{c4 -> 30}                    |{"c4":"30"}                    |
+----+----+----+---+----------------------------------------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

For Spark versions < 3.0 an UDF can be used:

```python
import json
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

def to_json(cols, values):
  data = {}
  for i, c in enumerate(cols):
    if values[i] != None:
      data[c] = values[i]
  return json.dumps(data)

u=F.udf(to_json, T.StringType())
df.withColumn("json", u(F.array([F.lit(c) for c in df.columns]),F.array(df.columns))).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am still in HDP with Spark 2.3.2 functions map_from_arrays is not found error

Comment: @Rata for older Spark versions an udf can be used

Comment: if values[i] != None  - didn't worked for me , so i changed to if len(values[i]) >0: instead got the first set of required output. Will group by and Apply sturct on data to get desired output

Comment: When I try to write back to file these string are written witth \" for " df = df.withColumn("jsongrp",F.lit('1'))
df_2=df.groupby('jsongrp').agg(F.collect_list('json').alias("ingestion_connection_details"))
results = df.toJSON().map(lambda j: json.loads(j)).collect()
with open('/hadoopData/bdipoc/poc/logs/data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(results, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)

Comment: which Python version do you use?